# Not authorized error on creating a durable subscriber to a Topic

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, publish-subscribe

I am facing some issues in creating a durable subscriber to a Topic .
This is the error message I get when creating a durable subscription to a topic –

JMS Exception :: com.ibm.mq.jms.BrokerCommandFailedException: Broker command failed: MQRCCF_NOT_AUTHORIZED Reason code 3081

I am able to create a normal/regular subscriber.

Since I am just starting out on queues/topics, want to know if this is because of insufficient permission?
Currently I am arbitarily setting the subscriber name and clientID while creating the durable subscriber. Should these values be administratively set on the server side before using them on the client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is definitely a problem of insufficient permission, that must be configured on server side, according to [IBM Message Broker documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.mft.doc%2Faq20813_.htm) :

> You are not authorized to perform the requested action. Authorization settings for the broker are handled by the system administrator using the Topics Hierarchy editor.

I'm not very familiar with IBM's jms broker however (and neither with websphere for that matter), so maybe someone more experienced with the configuration could be of greater help here ;)

Comment: Thanks, I also thought on the same lines, wanted to confirm :)

Comment: You seem to be using WebSphere MQ v6.x. Have been able to resolve the problem?